# JS - How to use on an OnePage the sessionStorage?

Tags: javascript, html

I do have a `OnePage website`, where I can add some notes to a list. Usually I do it with `copy & paste` function

On each click of `Add to the list` button on my Website, Javascript generats HTML. So the new entry appends to the existing list.

I would like to save these entries, and if my Websites refreshes, it should be still available. Please note its an onePage website.

I do have also a remove button, where I can delete some entries, if I don't need anymore.

```
// save my entries
$(function() {
  sessionStorage["myEntries"] = $('#id_This_Is_The_ID_of_the_NewEntry_That_I_Want_To_Save');
});


// restore my saved entries - IMPORTANT OnLoad
  if (sessionStorage["myEntries"] != null) {
    var SavedContent = sessionStorage["myKey"];
    $("#id_Of_The_Place_Where_The_Saved_HTML_Should_Be_Paste").html(SavedContent);
  } 


// remove entry from saved list
$(document).on('click', '.class_RemoveEntry', function() {
  sessionStorage.removeItem($(this).parents('table').remove());
});
```

Unfortunately, it wont work my code. It should save it and if I refresh my website, it should restore it again. What do I wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You way want to try `localStorage`. `sessionStorage` only stores over a single session (until reload). It works in much the same way, just replace all instances of `sessionStorage` with `localStorage`.  I'd recommend looking at the [MDN Document](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage). Keep in mind `addItem()`, `getItem()`, and `removeItem()`.

I hope this can help you!